# Log in to CRM from ASP.NET

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm writing an application in which I have to log on to a CRM 2011 server from ASP.NET code.  I quickly found this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc156363.aspx

The problem I'm having is in this bit of code from that article:

```
//Create the Service
CrmService service = new CrmService();
service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
service.Url = crmurl;
```

Visual Studio can't resolve CrmService.  So I tried to add a web reference to this project and point the web reference at the CRM service I'm using.  The URL I'm getting from Settings->Customizations in CRM, and I'm using the Organization Service endpoint.  However, after I add that reference CrmService is still unresolvable.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you have linked a CRM 4 MSDN article, some things have changed so you might want try this one instead: [Authenticate Users with Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328497.aspx).

Then as an alternative you may want to try the `CrmConnection` class, its a helper library in `Microsoft.Xrm.Client`. It means you can use a connection string approach to authenticate with CRM (and let the class takes care of all the hard work).

```
var connection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=http://crm.contoso.com/xrmContoso; Domain=CONTOSO; Username=jsmith; Password=passcode;");
var service = new OrganizationService(connection);
var context = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(connection);
```

You can also keep the connection strings in `config` files makes life significantly easier.

Related articles:

- [Simplified Connection to Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg695810.aspx).
- [Sample: Simplified Connection Quick Start using Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj602970.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I am trying to use the " Authenticate Users with Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web Services." linked above, but VS cannot resolve the symbol SystemUser in the following line:
    SystemUser systemUser = organizationProxy.Retrieve....
Even though I added all of the libraries and references listed in the example.  In which namespace is SystemUser defined?

Comment: You will need to generate the early bound classes to use that. You need to run svcutil against your CRM organisation. That or you can use the late bound Entity class. Check the MSDN for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using standard AD authentication with a local environment this answer should work fine: [How to Authenticate to CRM 2011?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090305/how-to-authenticate-to-crm-2011/15091928#15091928)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the login procedure is heavily dependent on the authentication provider you're targeting. I'm currently in the process of structuring that info in a pedagogic way on my blog so you're welcome to check it out and nag if it's too techy.

There are at the moment four such ways.

- Active directory
- Live id
- Federation
- Online federation

Which is applicable in your case, you should know already. If not, there's code for that too uploaded just a few days ago.

```csharp
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
...
public AuthenticationProviderType GetAuthenticationProviderType(Uri address)
{
  IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> organizationServiceManagement
    = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement
      <IOrganizationService>(address);
  return organizationServiceManagement.AuthenticationType;
}
```

Assuming that you're aiming for AD, you're in luck. It's the easiest.

```csharp
Uri organizationUrl = new Uri("http ... Organization.svc");
OrganizationServiceProxy organizationService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(
  organizationUrl, null, null, null);
```

If you're aiming for Live Id - that's stingy. I'm still trying to set up a graspable example. The ones at MSDN are just too heavy and confusing. At least when one's dense and lazy like me. More info at mentioned but undisclosed location.

Comment: You should post the direct links.

Comment: Also, re: the MSDN samples, I agree they are incredibly heavy handed, difficult to drill down to the relevant detail.

Comment: @JamesWood Which links are you referring to? If it's MSDN, Daryl already covered it (but I can rip-off from him). If it's to my blog, I prefer not to (afraid of being accused for self-promotion). Or did you mean something entirely different?

Comment: Your blog, if it contains the answer you should post it.

Comment: @JamesWood In principle, I agree. However, I'm insanely careful not to be accused for self-promotion (there are people around here who "answer" just so that they can generate traffic). Also, my blog is very easy to find, so that's not really a limitation. But links to other people's blogs, MSDN etc. I have no problems posting, of course. I just don't want to have to explain myself later on. I haven't seen you post links to your blog either (I'm assuming it's for the same reason).

Comment: I post direct links to my blog all the time. :D

Comment: @JamesWood OK, I'll take that into consideration the next time. And if anybody nags I'm going to say that "James made me do that", haha. Seriously, though, I think you're right. I'm too cautious.